# Convergence in probability degenerate case

Tags: probability

I understand the majority of this question, just when it comes to convergence in probability I don't understand why the solution restricts ε, when the theorem states $\forall \varepsilon >0$ and also surely $1-P(Y_n<1-ε)= 1-(1-ε)^n$?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem if $\varepsilon \gt 1$ is that some of the expressions become false in a way that does not aid understanding.  For example you would then have $\Pr(|Y_\cdot -1|\lt \varepsilon)=1$ which does not carry through the other equalities and so you would have to treat it as a distinct case to get that its limit is $1$.

Since you are actually only interested in small $\varepsilon$, you can avoid the special cases and shorten the proof by putting an upper limit on it.